# Get a list of results from by conditions

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qregexp

I will want to get a list of resaults by this condition of reg expression:

```
QRegExp rx(
            "(https://)"
            "(.*)"
            "(\\.jpg)"
          );
    
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;
    
while ((pos = rx.indexIn("jpegData_https://sfasdfsf_sadlfkjnsdlfjhn.jpgasodjfhasdfoho;usdoauhfsvc.asdfkpjhttps://adfklja32908jf0jmn01.jpg", pos)) != -1)
{
  list << rx.cap(0);
  pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
    
for(auto it : list)
{
  qDebug() << it;
}
```

I have got it:

```
"pegData_https://sfasdfsf_sadlfkjnsdlfjhn.jpgasodjfhasdfoho;usdoauhfsvc.asdfkpjhttps://adfklja32908jf0jmn01.jpg"
```

I need to get:

1. `https://sfasdfsf_sadlfkjnsdlfjhn.jpg`
2. `https://adfklja32908jf0jmn01.jpg`

Please, help me, what is wrong in QRegExp condition?

Comment: Why do you use `[]` inside `rx`?

Comment: @jarod42, sry, it is a typo, fixed.

Comment: It explains why your matching began with `peg` as `p` is in `[htps]`. then paddy answer the other part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, matching is greedy.  Your desired behavior should simply be a case of calling [setMinimal(true)](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setMinimal) on your QRegExp.

*e.g.*

```
QRegExp rx("(https://)(.*)(\\.jpg)");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```